# How to debug site locally if static resources are on a CDN?

Tags: html, testing, nginx, local, cdn

I have a website that I'm creating. Ultimately, all of the static resources (images, javascript, css, etc.) will end up on a CDN. However, while designing this site in a local server, I want my hrefs to pull the images locally.

How can I have `href="images/logo.png"` for my local site and `href="http://example.com/cdn/static/images/logo.png"` on the production site without using dynamic page generation (i.e. the simplest effective solution)?  All the ideas I've thought of involve manually creating scripts to pass over the html files, but this solution seems clunky.  Is there a more elegant way?

Also, if it helps, I just started using nginx.  Maybe there's some kind of rewrite rule for the urls that would accomplish my goal easily?

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information: Every method that exists to solve this is an ugly one.

- Overwriting the CDN domain so it will point to your localhost. (Nasty but quick fix?)
- Using JS variable to overwrite this (Bad idea)
- Replacing CDN string in all files with a regex. (Not that far off from dynamic page generation)

I would go for the first option.